# Vue/Vuetify - Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue and Vuetify. I just created quick app to check both of them. But I am a running into issues in beginning. The vue fails to identify vuetify components despite following all the steps outlined in document. The error is like below -

> vue.runtime.esm.js?ff9b:587 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:
>    - did you register the component correctly? For recursive
>   components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src\App.vue

You can access the entire code at sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/40rqnl8kw

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're likely experiencing a problem with the order of your operations. You're defining your own `App` component that uses the `v-app` component before you've even told Vue to make use of it, so Vue assumes you're using your own custom `v-app` component.

Place `Vue.use(Vuetify)` before starting any Vue instances via `new Vue()` that require Vuetify components, or place it within the component definitions themselves right at the top of the `<script>` tag after importing Vue and Vuetify within the single file component. Don't worry if you have more than one `Vue.use(Vuetify)` statement because only the first one will do anything--all subsequent calls will simply do nothing.

---

**Original** - `Vue.use()` is called before `new Vue()`, resulting in an error.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: { App },
    template: "<App/>"
});

Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

**Fix** - Calling `new Vue()` after `Vue.use()` allows Vue to resolve the dependency correctly.

```
Vue.use(Vuetify);

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: { App },
    template: "<App/>"
});
```

Comment: ty!.. this fixes issue. I just wonder how can you do Vue.use(Vuetify) even before importing Vuetify in main.js

Comment: After taking a closer look, you can leave most of your `main.js` code as it was. Just move the `Vue.use()` before your `new Vue()`. The problem is that once your create the Vue instance, it's too late to do `Vue.use()` to tell Vue to use Vuetify. Order of operations is very important in programming! Here's an updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o5jxzr4xvz

Comment: In fact, check this out: you can totally do `Vue.use(Vuetify)` before the import! What matters is that you use `Vue.use(Vuetify)` before doing `new Vue()` on any Vue instances that use Vuetify components! https://codesandbox.io/s/o5jxzr4xvz

Comment: I swear I played around with order. May b I should have thought about it logically. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 19):

There is another reason for this error that I recently ran into.

I recently upgraded from Vuetify 1.5 to 2.x and even though I had the order of operations correct as in the currently accepted answer here I was still receiving the error about v-app being unknown:

> Unknown custom element: `<v-app>` - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

Turns out that the upgrade process requires the following addition to package.json devDependencies section which didn't originally exist in my vuetify 1.5x package:

```
"vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
```

(1.3.0 current version as of this writing)

Once I added that the error went away.

Comment: Similarly, I add a dev-dependency and it works:
"vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3"

Comment: If you `vue add vuetify` as indicated in the [Quick Start section](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/) it installs "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify", so that's a step in the right direction, @he-ming. Unfortunately for me it wasn't enough to migration to work.

Answer (score 10):

If you are coming from Google: for me it was breaking changes from v1 to v2, that made most Codepen examples useless.
I had to change this to get a very simple Vuetify app with navigation drawers to run again:

```
remove toolbar from <v-app toolbar>
replace v-toolbar with v-app-bar
replace v-app-bar-side-icon with v-app-bar-nav-icon
replace v-app-bar-title with v-toolbar
replace v-list-tile to v-list-item

replace all flat with text
```

Maybe this helps someone.

(edited to include cong yu's remark)

Comment: It seems the third line should read `replace v-app-bar-side-icon with  v-app-bar-nav-icon`, at least in `vuetify@2.x`.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** it looks like [**`VuetifyLoader`**](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/a-la-carte) will automatcially do that for you.

**Old Answer:** Another possible problem is if you have a la carte enabled you will need to also specify all the components that you want included:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuetify, {
  VApp, // required
  VNavigationDrawer,
  VFooter,
  VToolbar,
  VFadeTransition
} from 'vuetify/lib'
import { Ripple } from 'vuetify/lib/directives'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VApp,
    VNavigationDrawer,
    VFooter,
    VToolbar,
    VFadeTransition
  },
  directives: {
    Ripple
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

With vuetify **v2.x** you should register the vuetify plugin as follows :

```
import Vue from 'vue'

/** register vuetify plugin globally **/

import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
Vue.use(Vuetify)
const opts = {}
const vuetify= new Vuetify(opts)
/****/

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Vuetify **v3**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue'

/*****/
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify= createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})
/****/

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(vuetify)

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: as of Vuetify 3 Alpha this doesn't work, but the working example is `import * as components from "vuetify/components";
 import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";`. The full working example is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203764/4742336

Comment: In your answer for Vue3, the custom theme can not be included inside of custom element!.

Comment: @amirtbi can you explain more?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, You may take a look at the question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/76936901/7926619

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same issue. It was caused by the cache of the browser make sure to clear the cache as well.

Comment: Oh god, cleared it multiple times, but then some more and it finally refreshed. Hate Safari...

Answer (score 1):

You will get this error even after installing the official Vuetify 3 (Alpha), due to the standard demo version generated during the install lacking adding components, i.e:

```
    import * as components from "vuetify/components";
    import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

    const vuetify = createVuetify({
            components,
            directives,
        });
```

Thus the working version of `main.ts` for Vuetify 3 is:

```
    import "vuetify/styles"; // Global CSS has to be imported
    import { createApp } from "vue";
    import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
    import App from "./App.vue";
    import * as components from "vuetify/components";
    import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";
    
    const app = createApp(App);
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives,
    });

    app.use(vuetify).mount("#app");    
    // or app.use(vuetify); app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone like me new working on vue and nuxt. My mistake was that I did not put the s in the last. `buildModule` should be `buildModules`.

My nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
    buildModules:[
        "@nuxtjs/vuetify"
    ],
    module:[
        "@nuxtjs/axios"
    ],
    components:true
}
```

Comment: Checking for typos is good general advice, but doesn't seem to be part of the original question. Answers should give solutions to the specific question, not just anecdotes

Answer (score 0):

I was including vuetify via a submodule and the parent module did not include vuetify in its dependencies. To avoid the 'Unknown custom element' warning, I had to install the submodules dependencies like this:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```