# How can add custom theme of vuetify library inside of a web component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js, web-component

I've created a web component by Vue 3, and also vuetify 3 has been used. The link contains the codes of project : [vue-web-component](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amirtbi/vue-webcomponent/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000h2v6k7gaotu9m%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.069620253164565%252C46.930379746835435%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clligjv9s00hu2v6amwg4uj1i%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000b2v6k0y58lmu0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689y8r01522v6kh96kosrj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligjv9s00hu2v6amwg4uj1i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522SAVING%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fweb-component.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligm5pk02m92v6ar3spskd0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cllignuq003le2v6aywhxouw9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000f2v6kif7dz18o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cll6899230004d8i33k6i8xxk%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689anb00jw2v6k0nd911ux%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligmnb602sq2v6ajyjrzo2h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522comment%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cllignuq003le2v6aywhxouw9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

When I run the command `npm run build`, the web component is built and the vuetify components work correctly inside of the web component, But, the custom theme, that i have defined inside my web-component.ts file, does not work properly!.
How can use my custom theme?